# Google can't record now as Duo is recording

Tags: google, audio-recording

[image]Hi All

Whenever I am making call in Duo some Error message is coming in screen like Google can't record now as Duo is recording.and while Playing pubg and stream in Omlet arcade same Error is coming like Omlet arcade can't record now as Pubg is recording. Can any one solve this issue please

Comment: What is your device and Android version (there is a difference between pre Android 10 those running Android 10+)?

Comment: IQOO3. Android Version -11